# How to prevent the player from going on top of object when moving?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The player goes on top of some objects when he walks toward them, how can I prevent that from happening?  Here is an example image of that:

[image]

I did not jump to be on the couch but yet it still goes on top of it when I walk to it. Here is my player information:

[image]

I don't want to change the player's movement, but I don't want it to go on top of objects when I'm walking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The character controller `Step Offset` solves this problem by increasing it value, but you may find that after adding the value, the character controller does not generate any gravitational force on its own.

[image]

To solve the problem of gravity, it is enough to first get the component.

```cs
private CharacterController controller;
public void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}
```

And then apply gravity to the object with the following instructions, you have already obtained the `moveInput` axis with the `Input.GetAxis` method.

```cs
private Vector3 velocity;
private void Update()
{
    var moveInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

    // === AFTER CALCULATING MOVE INPUT
    
    controller.Move(moveInput*Time.deltaTime);

    velocity += Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(velocity); // Apply Gravity

    if (controller.isGrounded) velocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `Step Offset` in character controller `0`. More info on it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html)